# HOW CAN I CALL THE DISPATCHER WITHPOUT GETTING AN ERROR?

Tags: android

[image]
Why am i getting an error while calling a dispatcher yet i have imported all the dependencies required?strong text

Comment: Please do not use pixel rasters human brains interpret as rendered text: cut&paste the text into a *block quote*. Especially any error messages you hope to get support about. (While your at it, review capitalisation and spelling, in the title, too.)

Comment: Write your code instead of including a screenshot. This will facilitate debugging

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might be that your `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, annotated with `override`, does not override anything. Please note that the class you wrote this function in should `extend` `AppCompatActivity` or `Activity`.

Also, the function you want to override should exactly match, meaning function name, return type, and parameter types and order all match.

It might be that there are additional errors.